# Compare columns of different file and paste the contents if matches

Tags: awk

Can someone please help me with below. I have two different files and I need to join the files but with some condition.

**File1**

```
ABC,10,20,3
GHI,8,6,2
```

**File2**

```
ABC,5000
DEF,6000
GHI,1000
```

Required output is as below

All columns of file1 + 2nd column of file2 where 1st column of file 1 matches with 1st column of file 2

**Output expected**

```
ABC,10,20,3,5000
GHI,8,6,2,1000
```

Comment: What have you tried? since your first column appears to be lexically sorted, it should be trivial using the `join` command

Answer (score 1):

```
join -t',' -1 1 -2 1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.2 <(sort FILE1) <(sort FILE2)

ABC,10,20,3,5000
GHI,8,6,2,1000
```

- Field separator (t) = ','
- `join -1 1` = FILE1 column 1, `-2 1` = FILE2 column 1
- `-o` = output, `1.1` = FILE1.column 1, ...

Comment: Or for the lazy ones: `join -t',' <(sort FILE1) <(sort FILE2)`